# Why does Tomcat give a 404 error message even though the project is there?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat

I am trying to run a project which has been already developed on a friend's computer. Although I did every configuration correctly I am getting `The requested resource is not available` message from tomcat when I try to load it. 
Tomcat is running correctly.

This is the way I tried to run the project. 
Configured everything, started the server, Deployed the project.

this is my `build.properties` file.

```
# Ant properties for building the STBSPro

appserver.home=C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.41
# for Tomcat 5 use $appserver.home}/server/lib
# for Tomcat 6 use $appserver.home}/lib
appserver.lib=${appserver.home}/lib
#appserver.lib=C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\lib

deploy.path=${appserver.home}/webapps


tomcat.manager.url=http://localhost:8090/manager/html
tomcat.manager.username=user
tomcat.manager.password=password


db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cashierdb
db.user=root
db.pw=root
```

I am running the server outside, server is not installed into Eclipse.(I use Spring Tool Suite)
in my `server.xml` file I changed the port to 8090.

in here, Is my `tomcat.manager.url` correct?

Do I have any other configurations to edit in order to run the project?

My server log does not give a single message in it.

Comment: [](http://gagandeepbali.uk.to:8080/manager/html), this URL is definitely working, so it seems the URL has nothing in it. Are you sure, the logs, do not point any exceptions being raised, in some other direction. Do check them thoroughly, once again :-)

Comment: Do I have to put my server, my IDE  and the work space at the same location? Currently I do not have my server on the location where I have put my IDE and the work space

Comment: Naa, that is not necessary. Since IDE and the server, are two different thingies. Never used any IDE before, hence, cannot say much, as to how to go about it in `Eclipse`. I am running my Apache, alone, with no `Eclipse`, from my home computer, for free. So just checked, it if I am able to see this manager page, through this URL as posted. So the answer is __"YES, indeed. The URL is working fine, so problem lies somewhere else :-)"__

Comment: yes I can log in to manager page. I think my project is not identified or eclipse does not identify the path correctly. I am confused and lost.